# Transit through Australia, different carriers - go through immigration?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, syd

I bought a ticket from Fiji to Europe from Cathay airlines but it involves both Cathay and air Pacific.
I stop over at Sydney from Suva.
I don't need a transit visa but need to recheck my baggage from Sydney to Europe because I change carriers.
Can this be done without leaving the transit lounge?

Comment: Are you _sure_ you will need to recheck baggage? "Because I change carriers" is not a reason to assume that; airlines routinely transfer baggage between each other for passengers who are connecting on a single booking.

Answer (score 2):

Fiji Airways (also known as Air Pacific) is a Oneworld "Connect Partner", while Cathay Pacific is a Oneworld member. They also have codeshare agreements.

As long as the two flights are on a single ticket, you should be able to do through check-in of your luggage to your final destination, and will not need to reclaim and re-check it in Sydney. You should not need to go through immigration (passport control) or customs.

Provided you are within the conditions for transit without visa, you won't need a visa.